# Php autoplay audio sms mms

Tags: php, audio, sms, autoplay, mms

Is there a way of embedding code, maybe php? Into a sms or mms message which will autoplay an audio file, without the users consent? Ie a sound file plays when a person opens the text message?

Found so far that html autoplay is blocked if the file contains audio by ios and android. However sms and mms are independent of Internet browsers. Not sure if the devices themselves block audio files? Just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: “Can you embed code into a text message and/or audio file” - no. Technically there’s buffer overflow type things that could process a payload, I guess, but would be pretty high severity bugs. And even if that existed, it wouldn’t rely on PHP’s interpreter to parse and execute code. If this could be done, I’d assume it would be a documented feature, and would be manufacture-specific. If this feature did exist, I’d also assume there’d be a toggle to disable it because it would be very annoying, especially for spam SMS